# I can't create a type definition file for "thingspeakclient" library

Tags: typescript

In my node/typescript project with express I would like to use `thingspeakclient` package. There is not any existing type definitions file for that package, so I decide to write one (for my very first time).

What I have:

1. Created folder `src/@types/thingspeakclient`
2. Created file `index.d.ts` with this content:

   ```
       declare module "thingspeakclient";
       declare interface TSCKeys {
           writeKey: string;
           readKey: string;
       }
       declare class ThingSpeakClient {
           constructor(opts: any);
           attachChannel(channelId: number, keys: TSCKeys, callback: Function): void;
       }
   ```

Now, in any TS file with for example this `import * as TSC from "thingspeakclient";` I want to use something like this:
`var a = new TSC.ThingSpeakClient();`

But in the runtime I see this error:
**`TypeError: TSC.ThingSpeakClient is not a constructor`**

Right now, I want to use just this 1 function, and yes, this package is really easy - so I don't have problem to re-write it to TS, but *I would like to learn how to write valid type definitions...*

Is there anybody who can tell me what I'm doing wrong??

**Update 1:**
I did a change suggested by cevek, but it still doensn't work:

Usage:

```
    import {ThingSpeakClient} from "thingspeakclient";
    var a = new ThingSpeakClient({});
```

Is converted to this Javascript:

```
    var thingspeakclient_1 = require("thingspeakclient");
    var a = new thingspeakclient_1.ThingSpeakClient({});
```

But problem is, when this JS package is used directly in JS, it must be use just like that (notice - there is no 'namespace'):

```
    var tsc = require("thingspeakclient");
    var a = new tsc({});
```

You can see, the returned object from require is directly used as a class...

Just for the clarity - original **simplified** JS code for *thingspeakclient* package:

```
    var ThingSpeakClient = function(opts) {
      //constructor
    };

    ThingSpeakClient.prototype.attachChannel = function(channelId, keys, callback) { }
    // next function definitions...
    // next ...
    // and at the end of file:
    module.exports = ThingSpeakClient;
```

Full class is here:
https://github.com/imwebgefunden/thingspeakclient_node/blob/master/thingspeakclient.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way if you really want use [commonjs module pattern](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9229)

```
declare namespace TSC {
    export interface TSCKeys {
        writeKey: string;
        readKey: string;
    }
    export class ThingSpeakClient {
        constructor(opts: any);
        attachChannel(channelId: number, keys: TSCKeys, callback: Function): void;
    }    
}


declare module 'thingspeakclient' {
    import ThingSpeakClient = TSC.ThingSpeakClient;
    export = ThingSpeakClient;
}

import * as ThingSpeakClient from "thingspeakclient";
var a = new ThingSpeakClient(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put inside [your module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-plugin-d-ts.html) your classes and interfaces

```
declare module 'thingspeakclient' {
    export interface TSCKeys {
        writeKey: string;
        readKey: string;
    }
    export default class ThingSpeakClient {
        constructor(opts: any);
        attachChannel(channelId: number, keys: TSCKeys, callback: Function): void;
    }
}

import ThingSpeakClient from "thingspeakclient";
var a = new ThingSpeakClient();
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it doesn't work :-(
I made your suggested change and VS code started to show "appropriate" intelliSense and so on. But generated JS code still looks bad:
`var thingspeakclient_1 = require("thingspeakclient");
var a = new thingspeakclient_1.ThingSpeakClient({});`

Comment: add `default` - `export default class ThingSpeakClient` and `import ThingSpeakClient from "thingspeakclient"; new ThingSpeakClient() `

Comment: I tried to add `default` - but it doesn't work - VSC starts to complain `A default export can only be used in an ecmascript-style module`. So I removed it. Instead of that, I just used another "import" command - `import ThingSpeakClient = require("thingspeakclient");` a that work nice! So thank you!